# Bousfield $p$-completion on spectra

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy, bousfield-localization

Bousfield p-completion on spaces is a functor $(-)^{\wedge p}$ whose main property is that a map $f:X\rightarrow Y$ induces an isomorphism $f_{\ast}:H_\ast(X,\mathbb{F}_{p})\rightarrow H_\ast(Y,\mathbb{F}_p)$ if and only if $f^{\wedge p}:X^{\wedge p}\rightarrow Y^{\wedge p}$ is a homotopy equivalence.

Let $X$ be now be a connective CW spectra, it is known that $H\mathbb{F}_p$-localization agrees with $M\mathbb{F}_p$-localization (both on X, the latter is referred as the $p$-completion). Let $f:E\rightarrow F$ a map between two connective CW spectra, is there any connection between $f^{\wedge p}$ and $({H\mathbb{F}_p})_{\ast}(f)$ (or $({H\mathbb{F}_p})^{\ast}(f)$)?, of course, an analogous version of the previous property is desirable, although there may be more restrictive conditions so that this property holds.

Comment: It can very well happen that the map is zero in homology, but is not nullhomotopic, e.g. almost any map between shifts of sphere spectra. In some sense, the more detailed relationship is described by the Adams spectral sequence.

Comment: @LennartMeier Do you mean a map $f$ with $H_\ast(f,\mathbb{F}_p)=0$ but $f^{\wedge p}\not\simeq\ast$?

Comment: Yes. This is fullfilled for any map $\Sigma^n\mathbb{S} \to \mathbb{S}$ with $n$ positive, whose order is a power of $p$, e.g. the Hopf map with $n=1$ and $p=2$.

Comment: In view of the way the question is formulated, an obvious answer is $(H\mathbb{F}_p)_*(f)=(H\mathbb{F}_p)_*(f^{\wedge p})$, (and similarly for cohomology), is this what is really asked for?

Comment: @user43326 Actually I had the suspicion that (under some restrictions) $(H\mathbb{F}_p)_\ast(f)$ is an isomorphism if and only if $f^{\wedge p}$ is a stable homotopy equivalence.

Comment: @VictorTC As a matter of fact it is more or less the definition of the localization (p-completion is the localization with respect to $HF_p$)

Comment: Besides, it is in your first paragraph, or am I missing something?

Comment: @user43326 No, I meant this property is well known on topological spaces, but besides the common name 'p-completion', its definition on spectra looks quite different.

Comment: OK, now I understood your post. It is actually easier to construct and requited properties for spectra than spaces, but the point is that your "main property" is a part of the definition of categorical localizations.  So if you accept the fact that it is a localization, then you also accept that the property holds...

Comment: @user43326 Thank you!, I checked the characterization of $E_{\ast}$-localization according to Bousfield's paper, and indeed this property follows from that.

Comment: Welcome.  It is as a matter of fact the definition of the localization with respect to a class of morphism (here $E_*$-equivalences) in any category.